# Reduce number of lines in multiline TextView if not all lines fit

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, remoteview

I have a vertical `LinearLayout` with a multiline `TextView` set to have a layout_weight of 1, and below that a more complex layout that wraps its content. If there isn't enough room in the outer `LinearLayout`, I want the number of lines shown in the `TextView` to be reduced. Instead, the bottom half of the bottom line just gets clipped.

Is there any way around this? This is in an app widget, so I can't use custom views.

Simplified layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start|bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:maxLines="2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <!-- ... sized content ... -->

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A time ago I had to mess with this too, basically within an IRC client which receives hundreds of lines per tab, and sadly, the response is no, there's not any mechanism to automatically control the buffer of the `TextView`.

So I had to implement an infinite loop `Thread` (which I would later convert into a `Service`) which takes the number of lines of the current `TextView` and if it exceeds a certain amount, it's truncated from the beggining of the buffer (the oldest lines get removed).

I'll attach what have I done, maybe it might help you.

```
static void FreeTextBuffer() {
  final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
  final Spanned sptxt = (Spanned) tv.getText();

  // This is a workaround, seems that Html.toHtml() passing directly the text makes the system stale - this works
  final SoftReference<String> texto = new SoftReference<String>(Html.toHtml((Spanned) sptxt.subSequence(0, sptxt.length())));
  final int matches = StringUtils.countMatches(texto.get(), "<br>");

  if (matches > (3 * maxLines) / 2) {
    // Here I'm counting the amount of \n to cut off (the 0.5 * matches is a tuned solution that works for me)
    int cutpoint = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 0.5 * matches; i++)
      cutpoint = texto.get().indexOf("<br>", (cutpoint < 0)? 0 : cutpoint + 1);

    // Just for the Thread...
    final int forUIth = cutpoint;

    if (cutpoint > -1) {
      ((Activity) globvars.getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          synchronized(tv) { 
            tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(texto.get().substring(forUIth)));
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is in a remote view (in app widget), so I can't get a reference to the TextView.